# Change tick size on colorbar of seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, colorbar, seaborn

I want to increase the tick label size corresponding to the colorbar in a heatmap plot created using the `seaborn` module. As an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
ax = sns.heatmap(arr)
```

Usually I would change the `labelsize` keyword using the `tick_params` method on a colorbar axes object, but with the `heatmap()` function I can only pass kwargs to the colorbar constructor. How can I modify the tick label size for the colorbar in this plot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you call `heatmap` the colorbar axes will get a reference at the `axes` attribute of the figure object. So you could either set up the figure ahead of time or get a reference to it after plotting with `ax.figure` and then pull the colorbar axes object out that way:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
ax = sns.heatmap(arr)

cax = ax.figure.axes[-1]
cax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how to get at that `axes` object.

Comment: Note that you can also pass a specific axes object that the colorbar will be drawn into, but that's overkill if you're happy with the default positioning.

Answer (score 9):

A slightly different way that avoids `gcf()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(arr, ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

I almost always start my plots this way, by explicitly creating a `fig` and `ax` object. It's a bit more verbose, but since I tend to forget my `matplotlib-foo`, I don't get confused with what I'm doing.